# How to configure the return string based on user input?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a scenario where I am supposed to add a feature to the existing code and this feature is supposed to take input of from the user and form a string. Right now by default the code ships with **full name** = **firstname** and **lastname**. But I am supposed to make it configurable according to user demand, where the user can add any property like location or phone number to display with the full name. So for e.g the format can be **[firstname + lastname + location or lastname + firstname + phonenumber  ]**.

And I have managed to take the users input and store it in a variable called **test** and here is the code for it.

```
[DataMember]
        public string FullName
        {
            get
            {
                string test = "";
                test = Services.GetService<IGlobalOptionsBrokerDataAccess>().test1();
                return string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", this.FirstName, this.MiddleName, this.LastName);
            }
            set
            {
                _fullName = value;
            }
        }
```

So how can I make it work dynamically? Here the screenshot of how the value is available in the **test** variable. If the user wants to have ManagerID then how can I make it work dynamically?
[image]

Is there anything more I should provide so that it would be easier for you guys out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better solution other than the mentioned above.

```
 string[] columnNames = format.Split(new char[] { ',' });
            string userFullNameAsPerFormat = string.Empty;
            string defaultFullName = this.FirstName + " " + this.LastName;

        // Get the Type object corresponding to MyClass.
        Type myType = typeof(Courion.BusinessServices.Access.ProfileDTO);
                    // Get the PropertyInfo object by passing the property name.
                    PropertyInfo myPropInfo = myType.GetProperty(item.Trim());
    userFullNameAsPerFormat += (string) myPropInfo.GetValue(this) + " ";
```

Answer (score 1):

May not be an optimal solution, but this is what I thought of quickly. Making your format string dynamic could help you.

```
var posDict = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    {"FirstName","{0}" },
    {"MiddleName","{1}" },
    {"LastName","{2}" }};

var test = "FirstName,LastName,MiddleName";
var posString = "";
foreach (var prop in test.Split(','))
    posString += $"{posDict.First(x => x.Key == prop).Value} ";

return string.Format(posString, this.FirstName, this.MiddleName, this.LastName);
```